# Change image of a selected ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I'm using the method below to select multiple items in the list and get delete them. I would like to change the icons image of the item I selected, however I did not find at what time I can do this, can anyone help me?

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = listview.getCheckedItemCount();
            actionMode.setTitle(checkedCount + getString(R.string.selected_item_list));
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i < 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            Object object = adapter
                                    .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                            adapter.remove(delivery);
                        }
                    }
                    actionMode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_delete, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            adapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean to the data object in your adapter. Suppose you've got ArrayAdapter. Add some kind of "selected" field in the MyDataObject, and toggle it when you "select" the row.

Override getView in the adapter (you'll need a custom Adapter, btw. I'd just extend ArrayAdapter). When you render the row, if the "selected" field is true, show the "other" image.

When you click the button, call 'notifyDataSetChanged' on the adapter. The will cause the visible rows to refresh themselves (and call getView for each).

Since you only want images to change when you click the button, you'll need to have some kind of global boolean, so the getView won't show the image until the button has been clicked.